# The derivative of complex quadratic form

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms

Is there any way to represent the derivative of this complex quadratic statement into a compact matrix form?

$${x^{{*^T}}}Ax = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{a_1}{e^{ - j{\theta _1}}}}& \cdots &{{a_n}{e^{ - j{\theta _n}}}} 
\end{array}} \right]A\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{a_1}{e^{j{\theta _1}}}} \\ 
   \vdots  \\ 
  {{a_n}{e^{j{\theta _n}}}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$

Comment: Derivative with respect to $x$ I suppose.

Comment: With respect to what are you deriving? A particular $\theta_i$? The vector $[\theta_1, ..., \theta_n]$?

Comment: Actually, I want to find the derivative of ${x^H}Ax$ with respect to both $\left[ {{a_1}, \cdots ,{a_n}} \right]$ and $\left[ {{\theta _1}, \cdots ,{\theta _n}} \right]$. In  my problem ${x^H}Ax$ is a function of both $a_i$ and $\theta _i$ where $\forall i = 1 \cdots n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the (Wirtinger) derivatives of $x^H A x$  (using $(\cdot)^H$ for conjugate transpose) with respect to $x$ and $x^*$  are just $A^T x^*$ and $A x$, respectively. If you want to derive with respect to $\theta$, use the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial x^H A x}{\partial \theta} = 
\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial \theta}\cdot\frac{\partial x^H A x}{\partial x^*}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\cdot\frac{\partial x^H A x}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial x^*}{\partial \theta} A x + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} A^T x^* .$$

In your case, $\frac{\partial x^*}{\partial \theta}$ is simple, it is just a diagonal matrix with $-j a_i {\rm e}^{-j \theta_i}$ on its diagonal ($i=1, 2, ..., n$). For the derivative with respect to $a$, the same principle applies. Your partial derivatives are nothing but ${\rm e}^{-j \theta_i}$ in this case.

Comment: Could you explain why the derivative with respect to vector $ \theta $ is real? The matrix $A$ is neither Hermitian nor skew-Hermitian so the value of $ {x^H}Ax $ is a complex number.  Let $ {x^H}Ax = f\left( {a,\theta } \right) + ig\left( {a,\theta } \right) $ where $a = \left[ {{a_1}, \cdots ,{a_n}} \right]$ and $ \theta  = \left[ {{\theta _1}, \cdots ,{\theta _n}} \right] $ , then $ \frac{{\partial {x^H}Ax}}{{\partial \theta }} = \frac{{\partial f\left( {a,\theta } \right)}}{{\partial \theta }} + i\frac{{\partial g\left( {a,\theta } \right)}}{{\partial \theta }}$ which is not real.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I'm so used to seeing quadratic forms that for some reason I assumed the $A$ is Hermitian. You are of course correct, the answer is only real-valued if $A$ is Hermitian. I edited my reply.

Comment: @Saeed: Something else that needs clarification? Any further explanations you'd like to have?

Comment: No. I don't think so. Thanks.

Comment: @Florian could you please clarify, the derivative of $x^HAx$ with respect to $x$ is $A^Tx$ and not $A^Hx$. Right?

Comment: Neither nor ;-) The derivative of $x^H A x$ with respect to $x$ is $(x^H A)^T = A^T x^*$, as I wrote in the reply (here $x^*$ is just the complex conjugate).

Comment: Should it be multiplied by 2?

Comment: @CaliShulz no, the factor 2 only appears in the real-valued case. In the complex-valued case there is no factor 2.