# A simple question regarding complex matrix differentiation

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

I have a complex matrix $\mathbb{A}$ and a complex vector $\mathbb{b}$. How to find the derivative of $$\mathbb{x}^H\mathbb{Ax}$$

and $$\mathbb{b}^H\mathbb{x}$$

with respect to $\mathbb{x}$. Where $\mathbb{x}$ is also complex. Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4062655/339790).

Comment: Shouldn't the matrix be Hermitian? Shouldn't there be a $\mathbb{x}^H\mathbb{b}$ term?

Comment: Why not use $*$ instead of $H$? Why not use `\mathbf` instead of `\mathbb`?